# Create instance with name obtained dynamically from command line input in python

Tags: python, class, oop, variables

I'm working with argparse now, and I am at point where it hit me that I might want/need to create instances of a class, but the name of the instance comes from a command line variable stored by argparse. 
How do I do that? Bash's parameter expansion immediately came to mind, but Python doesn't have anything like that, as far as I know.

Specifically: 
Let's say I have a 'name' argument with argparse that stores ..the name of something. So it looks like

```
{name: 'somename'}
```

in the argparse namespace dictionary, after the parsing is done.

Now, say I want to instantiate a class *someclass*, and give it the name stored in the 'name' variable, i.e. *somename*, here, such that

```
somename = someclass()
```

How do I 'expand' the variable so that I can use its value as the name of a class instance?

Answer (score 0):

By using globals() or locals() function, we can change the string into a variable name and assign a value to it.

```
d = {'name': 'somename'} 

class MyClass:
    x = 5

globals()[d['name']]=MyClass()
```

`somename.x` will give `5`